# Buildozer compiles apk, but it crashes on android

Tags: android, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, apk, kivy

I am able to build an .apk, but after I install it on my android phone it simply crashes at startup. My thoughts for failing is that I am using 3rd party libraries e.g(beautifulsoup).

This is how my imports look in main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

import time, os, random, urllib2, re, cookielib as cj

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from functools import partial
```

I'm running mavericks 10.9.3

Does it have something to do with buildozer.spec file?
I've tried adding BeautifulSoup to app requirements, but it doesn't change a thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post logcat.?

Comment: I am not quite sure about the logcat, do I only run 'buildozer android logcat'? If yes, thats what I get:
$ buildozer android logcat
    # Check configuration tokens
    # Ensure build layout
    # Check configuration tokens

Comment: You do need to add all non-core Python modules to your buildozer.spec requirements. They are not picked up automatically. After you've added it, post a logcat of your run attempt.

Comment: I am using 'requirements = kivy, BeautifulSoup' at the moment, functools,time,os are all core modules, right?
Here is the full log: http://pastebin.com/ZyCipwwu

Comment: I had exactly the same problem a couple of months ago and raised a question in the kivy user support group(google that and no harm asking there). I asked the question there, but never got my problem solved. bs4 just simply didn't seem to work with kivy/buildozer. However, the people working on it are constantly fixing bugs and issues users have, so it may be solved by now. I am thinking I may raise the question again and hopefully get it sorted

Comment: I found the thread I mentioned. It seems my problem was with a file called _htmlparser, that bs4 seems to depend on. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/VQKyk_kTO1I

Comment: It seems I will have to wait till it gets fixed also, just for curiosity, should I do "requirements = kivy, BeautifulSoup" or "requirements = kivy, beautifulsoup4", both of those seem to build the .apk but yet it crashes on android. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Did you by any chance solve this issue?

Comment: Hey, Totem, no I haven't. I simply left it with a hope to be fixed in the future, which apparently didn't happen yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well, but I was (apparently) able to get everything working fine with a workaround.  Since it doesn't look like you posted a logcat, I'll assume you ran into the same issue I did.

Yes, you do need to list beautifulsoup4 as a requirement in your spec.  From looking into bs4's code, it looks like bs4 is willing to use any of several "builders."  It supports HTMLParser, html5lib, or lxml.  I have no idea why we can't load HTMLParser, but it's actually the *least* preferred library of the three, and if it weren't for the fact that there's no try block around the import, it seems that everything would work fine (as long as one of the other parsing libraries was available).

With this in mind, I included one of the other libraries, and I decided to hack the import process so that Python would pretend _htmlparser loaded okay :)

This article was instructive: http://xion.org.pl/2012/05/06/hacking-python-imports/

The end result was something like this:

```
import imp
import sys

class ImportBlocker(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.black_list = args

    def find_module(self, name, path=None):
        if name in self.black_list:
            return self

        return None

    def load_module(self, name):
        module = imp.new_module(name)
        module.__all__ = [] # Necessary because of how bs4 inspects the module

        return module

sys.meta_path = [ImportBlocker('bs4.builder._htmlparser')]
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I also added html5lib to the requirements in buildozer.spec.

Now, is this the right way to solve the problem?  I don't know.  The best approach would probably be to request that the author fix it.  It might be as simple as to put the import in a try block.  Nevertheless, this is the approach I've gone with for the moment, and it is at least an interesting exercise, and a way to test your app until a better fix comes along.

Additionally, I should warn you that I only did this recently, so I can't 100% guarantee that it won't cause any problems, but at a minimum, it's worked well enough to get my app running and scraping the particular website I was interested in.  Good luck!

Comment: I was struggling with this as well and your fix allowed it to run on Kivy Android.  Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU Will! I have been struggling with bs4 for android through buildozer for far too long. Your work around has worked for me and I cant thank you enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question is some years old. I think the answer @Will gave was fantastic but unfortunately, in my case, I couldn't use it because html5lib was too slow for what I was making. So this is for reference; for anyone who absolutely must use the built-in parser. It's not pretty but it's fairly manageable.

## The issue

After much investigation, I nailed down the cause of the problem. In the buildozer log, I noticed that there was a problem compiling the _htmlparser file with the log reading as follows (with my project path replaced with <project-path>):

```
Compiling <project-path>/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/mypackage/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py ...
SyntaxError: ("(unicode error) \\N escapes not supported (can't load unicodedata module)", ('<project-path>/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/mypackage/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py', 135, None, 'data = u"\\N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}"\n'))
```

Because it was failing to compile, it wasn't being included in the built apk file. So I looked at the file and at the line that was causing the problem: `data = u"\N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}"` which should actually be replaced by `data = u"\ufffd"`

## Quick-fix

Now the easy way out would be to modify the file right in the package. You could just edit the file mentioned in the error above which should, in theory, work but it's not recommended because every time the package gets re-installed or the code gets built from another machine the problem will be back.

## Marginally better fix

It would be nice if the fix was all packaged into our code, so drawing inspiration from @Will's answer, here is the code you would need to put in before your bs4 import:

```
import sys

class ImportFixer(object):
    def __init__(self, mname):
        self.mname = mname

    def find_module(self, name, path=None):
        if name == self.mname:
            return self
        return None

    def load_module(self, name):
        import _htmlparser as module
        module.__name__ = name
        return module

sys.meta_path = [ImportFixer('bs4.builder._htmlparser')]
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

The main difference is that you need to copy the _htmlparser.py file from the bs4 package to your current directory and fix the before mentioned line `data = u"\N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}"` with `data = u"\ufffd"`

Then, every time the bs4 module is imported, the import is magically intercepted and the local file is used.

#### Warning: if you ever update Beautiful Soup, you may need to use a more recent _htmlparser.py file in your project with the same fix made as needed.

## Final comment

If I made some typos, grammar mistakes or didn't make sense at all, keep in mind that I worked most of the weekend to fix this and quite frankly I'm not thinking straight. Comment if you have any questions and I'll reply and/or edit my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Hey, so it seems that the python -m compileall doesn't compile this file, so it's an issue with Python directly. This kind of stuff is better to be directly reported on the project rather than an explaination here :) edit: actually reported https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1060