# App crash with kivy and bs4

Tags: android, python, beautifulsoup, kivy, buildozer

I build the apk in the kivy VM and after building, when I open the app on android, crashed I get first this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _htmlparser
```

I search on the internet i and I found this solution: [Buildozer compiles apk, but it crashes on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952484/buildozer-compiles-apk-but-it-crashes-on-android)

But after do this, crash again but with another error, this:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html.parser. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

And now I don't know how can I do...I tried to replace `soup = BeautifulSoup(RESPONSE.content, "html.parser")` with `soup = BeautifulSoup(RESPONSE.content, "lxml")`
But I get the same error

In the buildozer.spec file i have this:
https://hastebin.com/ayepobufon.shell
And all the libraries are updated, I use python2 and Kivy VM to build apk with command `buildozer android debug`

Comment: Can you please provide further details such as your Python version, the versions of the libraries you are using, some example code where this happens, and how you build the app?

Comment: @DavideR. i added the extra info

Comment: already reported at https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1060