# How to ask ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER permission on Android with Kivy/Buildozer?

Tags: python, android, permissions, kivy, buildozer

Hi there and first of all a big thanks to all of you who helped me without knowing it. For a noob like me, stack overflow is really precious.

I'm new to coding, learned Python3 to see if I can, and trying to do an Android Application for my girlfriend's professionnal activity.

I scrape informations on her website, put those on a JSON file, modify those a little and use Kivy and Float Layout to add them on screen. The most advanced part (for me), is a function to make a phonecall on android.

All works really good on my PC (Ubuntu or Windows), but when it come to Android, it crash at launch (after "Loading" I get a blackscreen).

First, Buildozer asked for a lot of requirements (you will see that on the .spec file), after that problem was solved, I ran on an other one with an android permission denied ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER. I asked with the builddozer.spec and that's not good as you can see on logs.

I also used some code to ask in my main.py

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER])
```

and it returns that Permission as no ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER argument.

Can you give me a hand please ? I spent 2 days searching how to make it works and my skills (and google) are not enough.

My buildozer.spec :

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = ConcepTruelle

# (str) Package name
package.name = conceptruelle

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.conceptruelle

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,py

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,hostpython3,kivy==master,scrapy,jnius,pyjnius,requests,simplejson,openssl,android,prettyprinter,twisted,w3lib,attrs,lxml,parsel,cssselect,itemadapter,cryptography,pyopenssl,zlib_wrapper,macholib,pydispatch,pydispatcher,libxslt,libxml2,service_identity,pyasn1,pyasn1_modules,google-auth-oauthlib,android.permissions

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER,INTERNET,ACCEPT_HANDOVER,BROADCAST_STICKY,PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
```

My logs :

```
10-26 17:12:09.463  9229  9229 V SDL     : nativeSetupJNI()
10-26 17:12:09.466  9229  9229 V SDL     : AUDIO nativeSetupJNI()
10-26 17:12:09.468  9229  9229 V SDL     : CONTROLLER nativeSetupJNI()
10-26 17:12:09.494  9229  9229 D hidapi  : Initializing Bluetooth
10-26 17:12:09.495  9229  9229 D hidapi  : Couldn't initialize Bluetooth, missing android.permission.BLUETOOTH
10-26 17:12:09.525  9229  9229 V PythonActivity: Setting env vars for start.c and Python to use
10-26 17:12:09.525  9229  9229 V PythonActivity: Access to our meta-data...
10-26 17:12:09.529  9229  9229 I PythonActivity: Surface will NOT be transparent
10-26 17:12:09.529  9229  9229 V PythonActivity: onResume()
10-26 17:12:09.530  9229  9229 V SDL     : onResume()
10-26 17:12:09.557   604   942 W ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER from uid=10182 pid=9229
10-26 17:12:09.558   604   942 D PermissionCache: checking android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER for uid=10182 => denied (814 us)
10-26 17:12:09.562  9229  9229 V SDL     : surfaceCreated()
10-26 17:12:09.562  9229  9229 V SDL     : surfaceChanged()
10-26 17:12:09.563  9229  9229 V SDL     : pixel format RGB_565
10-26 17:12:09.565  9229  9229 V SDL     : Window size: 1080x1731
10-26 17:12:09.565  9229  9229 V SDL     : Device size: 1080x1920
10-26 17:12:09.578  9229  9229 V SDL     : nativeResume()
10-26 17:12:09.579  9229  9326 V SDL     : Running main function SDL_main from library /data/app/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle-OBg7Tkf0OmcdRT4L0eMfDQ==/lib/arm/libmain.so
10-26 17:12:09.579  9229  9326 V PythonActivity: appConfirmedActive() -> preparing loading screen removal
10-26 17:12:09.580  9229  9326 V SDL     : nativeRunMain()
10-26 17:12:09.582  9229  9326 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
10-26 17:12:09.582  9229  9326 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
10-26 17:12:09.583  9229  9326 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
10-26 17:12:09.583  9229  9326 I python  : /data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app
10-26 17:12:09.584  9229  9326 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
10-26 17:12:09.584  9229  9326 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
10-26 17:12:09.585  9229  9326 I python  : calculated paths to be...
10-26 17:12:09.585  9229  9326 I python  : /data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
10-26 17:12:09.590  9229  9326 I python  : set wchar paths...
10-26 17:12:09.730  9229  9326 I python  : Initialized python
10-26 17:12:09.730  9229  9326 I python  : AND: Init threads
10-26 17:12:09.734  9229  9326 I python  : testing python print redirection
10-26 17:12:09.738  9229  9326 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
10-26 17:12:09.739  9229  9326 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/core-oj.jar:/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/framework-oahl-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar:/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote_secondary': '11', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app:/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'True', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'portrait', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
10-26 17:12:09.742  9229  9326 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
10-26 17:12:09.743  9229  9326 I python  : AND: Ran string
10-26 17:12:09.743  9229  9326 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
10-26 17:12:10.081  9229  9326 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
10-26 17:12:10.081  9229  9326 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
10-26 17:12:10.102  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-10-26_0.txt
10-26 17:12:10.104  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
10-26 17:12:10.105  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
10-26 17:12:10.107  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.1 (default, Oct 26 2020, 11:01:07) 
10-26 17:12:10.107  9229  9326 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
10-26 17:12:10.109  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
10-26 17:12:10.111  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Analysing...
10-26 17:12:10.113  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
10-26 17:12:14.439  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
10-26 17:12:15.352  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
10-26 17:12:15.436  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
10-26 17:12:15.520  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
10-26 17:12:15.573  9229  9326 E libEGL  : validate_display:92 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
10-26 17:12:15.575  9229  9326 V SDL     : setOrientation() orientation=-1 width=800 height=600 resizable=true hint=
10-26 17:12:15.593  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
10-26 17:12:15.597  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
10-26 17:12:15.599  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@258.0 (GIT@8e59954, I0be83d0d26) (Date:09/22/17)'>
10-26 17:12:15.600  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
10-26 17:12:15.602  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 418'>
10-26 17:12:15.604  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
10-26 17:12:15.606  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
10-26 17:12:15.607  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
10-26 17:12:15.724  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
10-26 17:12:15.727  9229  9326 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
10-26 17:12:15.855  9229  9326 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
10-26 17:12:15.857  9229  9326 I python  :  2020-10-26 17:12:15 [kivy] WARNING: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
10-26 17:12:15.858  9229  9326 I python  :  2020-10-26 17:12:15 [kivy] WARNING: stderr: 2020-10-26 17:12:15 [kivy] WARNING: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
10-26 17:12:15.860  9229  9326 I python  :  2020-10-26 17:12:15 [kivy] WARNING: stderr: 2020-10-26 17:12:15
```

---

Edit :

Here is the code :

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
import scrapy
import os
import json
import pprint
import webbrowser
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config  
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from kivy.lang import Builder
from jnius import autoclass
from jnius import cast

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)  

Builder.load_string("""
<MyLabel1>
    text_size: self.size
    shorten: False
    markup: True
    background_color: 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, .2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.width, 92
<MyLabel2>
    text_size: self.size
    shorten: False
    markup: True
    background_color: 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, .3
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.width, 92
<MyTitle>
    markup: True
""")

class MyLabel1(Label):
    """
    A Label class with dark grey background, markups and wrapping
    """
    pass

class MyLabel2(Label):
    """
    A Label class with light grey background, markups and wrapping
    """
    pass

class MyTitle(Label):
    """
    A Label class with markups for the main title
    """
    pass

class AgendaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    A scraper who retrieve informations on ConcepTruelle's website
    """
    name = "agendaconceptruelle"
    start_urls = [
        'http://conceptruelle.fr/index.php/notre-agenda'
    ]
    while os.path.exists('agenda.json'): os.remove('agenda.json')

    def parse(self, response):
        for agenda in response.css("div.title-header.ic-title-header.ic-float-left"):
            yield {
                'title': agenda.css("a ::text").get(),
            }
        for agenda in response.css("div.title-cat.ic-title-cat.ic-float-right"):
            yield {
                'category': agenda.css(" ::text").get(),
            }
        for agenda in response.css("div.nextdate.ic-next-date.ic-clearfix"):
            yield {
                'date': agenda.css("span ::text").get(),
            }
        for agenda in response.css("div.nextdate.ic-next-date.ic-clearfix"):
            yield {
                'time': agenda.css("span.ic-single-starttime ::text").get(),
            }
        for agenda in response.css("div.place.ic-place"):
            yield {
                'location': agenda.css(" ::text").get(),
            }
        for agenda in response.css("div.descshort.ic-descshort"):
            yield {
                'description': agenda.css(" ::text").get(),
            }

class ConceptruelleApp(App):

    def build(self):
        """
        Scrape ConcepTruelle's website agenda and put it on screen
        4 buttons give access to website, social medias and phone number
        """
        def phonecall(self):
            """
            Make a Phone Call on Android with Jnius
            """
            Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
            Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')          
            PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')                                        
            intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)         
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "0600000000"))     
            currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity',                                                        
                PythonActivity.mActivity)
            currentActivity.startActivity(intent)
         
        def website(self):
            """
            Open ConcepTruelle's website
            """
            webbrowser.open("http://conceptruelle.fr/")

        def facebook(self):
            """
            Open ConcepTruelle's Facebook page
            """
            webbrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com/ConcepTruelle")

        def instagram(self):
            """
            Open ConcepTruelle's Instagram page
            """
            webbrowser.open("https://www.instagram.com/conceptruelle")
        
        # Main application : definition of title, labels and buttons put on a Float Layout
        fl = FloatLayout()
        lbl0 = MyTitle(text = "  [size=28][color=000000]L\'[/color][color=dd9514][i]Agenda[/i][/color] [color=000000][b]ConcepTruelle[/b][/size][/color]", markup=True, size_hint =(1, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.97})
        lbl1 = MyLabel1(text = event_title_1 + "\n" + agenda1, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':1.03})
        lbl2 = MyLabel2(text = event_title_2 + "\n" + agenda2, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.86})
        lbl3 = MyLabel1(text = event_title_3 + "\n" + agenda3, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.69})
        lbl4 = MyLabel2(text = event_title_4 + "\n" + agenda4, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.52})
        lbl5 = MyLabel1(text = event_title_5 + "\n" + agenda5, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.35})
        fl.add_widget(lbl0)
        fl.add_widget(lbl1)
        fl.add_widget(lbl2)
        fl.add_widget(lbl3)
        fl.add_widget(lbl4)
        fl.add_widget(lbl5)
        btn1 = Button(text = "Appel", size_hint =(.25, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.125, 'center_y':.05})
        btn1.bind(on_press=phonecall)
        btn2 = Button(text = "Site Web", size_hint =(.25, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.375, 'center_y':.05})
        btn2.bind(on_press=website)
        btn3 = Button(text = "Facebook", size_hint =(.25, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.625, 'center_y':.05})
        btn3.bind(on_press=facebook)
        btn4 = Button(text = "Instagram", size_hint =(.25, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.875, 'center_y':.05})
        btn4.bind(on_press=instagram)
        fl.add_widget(btn1)
        fl.add_widget(btn2)
        fl.add_widget(btn3)
        fl.add_widget(btn4)
        return fl

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # using Scrapy to get informations from ConcepTruelle's website and puting it in a JSON file
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
        "FEEDS": {
            "agenda.json": {"format": "json"},
        },
    })
    process.crawl(AgendaSpider)
    process.start()
    
    # Opening the created JSON file and using PPRINT to get strings
    with open("agenda.json") as f:
        agenda_list = json.load(f)
        pprint.pprint(agenda_list)
    
    # Modifying the JSON to fit requirements
    for agenda_dict in agenda_list:
        for k,v in agenda_dict.items():
            if v is not None and k == "time":
                agenda_dict[k] = "à " + str(agenda_dict[k])
            if v is None:
                agenda_dict[k] = "de 10:00 à 16:00"
            for k,v in agenda_dict.items():
                if k == "category" and v == "\n\t\t\t\t\tStage\t\t\t\t":
                    agenda_dict[k] = "[color=0aa7f5]" + str(agenda_dict[k]) + "[/color]"
                if k == "category" and v == "\n\t\t\t\t\tAtelier\t\t\t\t":
                    agenda_dict[k] = "[color=8113bd]" + str(agenda_dict[k]) + "[/color]"
                for k,v in agenda_dict.items():
                    agenda_dict[k] = v.replace('\t', '')
                    for k,v in agenda_dict.items():
                        agenda_dict[k] = v.replace('\n', '')
    
    # dumping the modified JSON file
    with open('agenda.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(agenda_list, outfile)
    
    # creating titles and labels with the JSON informations
    event_title_1 = str("[size=18] [b]" + agenda_list[5].get("category") + "[/b] [color=000000]-[/color] [b][color=dd9514]" + str(agenda_list[0].get("title")) + "[/b][/color][/size]")
    event_title_2 = str("[size=18] [b]" + agenda_list[6].get("category") + "[/b] [color=000000]-[/color] [b][color=dd9514]" + str(agenda_list[1].get("title")) + "[/b][/color][/size]")
    event_title_3 = str("[size=18] [b]" + agenda_list[7].get("category") + "[/b] [color=000000]-[/color] [b][color=dd9514]" + str(agenda_list[2].get("title")) + "[/b][/color][/size]")
    event_title_4 = str("[size=18] [b]" + agenda_list[8].get("category") + "[/b] [color=000000]-[/color] [b][color=dd9514]" + str(agenda_list[3].get("title")) + "[/b][/color][/size]")
    event_title_5 = str("[size=18] [b]" + agenda_list[9].get("category") + "[/b] [color=000000]-[/color] [b][color=dd9514]" + str(agenda_list[4].get("title")) + "[/b][/color][/size]")
    agenda1 = str("[color=000000][i] " + str(agenda_list[25].get("description")) + "[/i]\n Le " + str(agenda_list[10].get("date")) + " " + str(agenda_list[15].get("time")) + "\n Lieu : " + str(agenda_list[20].get("location")) + "[/color]")
    agenda2 = str("[color=000000][i] " + str(agenda_list[26].get("description")) + "[/i]\n Le " + str(agenda_list[11].get("date")) + " " + str(agenda_list[16].get("time")) + "\n Lieu : " + str(agenda_list[21].get("location")) + "[/color]")
    agenda3 = str("[color=000000][i] " + str(agenda_list[27].get("description")) + "[/i]\n Le " + str(agenda_list[12].get("date")) + " " + str(agenda_list[17].get("time")) + "\n Lieu : " + str(agenda_list[22].get("location")) + "[/color]")
    agenda4 = str("[color=000000][i] " + str(agenda_list[28].get("description")) + "[/i]\n Le " + str(agenda_list[13].get("date")) + " " + str(agenda_list[18].get("time")) + "\n Lieu : " + str(agenda_list[23].get("location")) + "[/color]")
    agenda5 = str("[color=000000][i] " + str(agenda_list[29].get("description")) + "[/i]\n Le " + str(agenda_list[14].get("date")) + " " + str(agenda_list[19].get("time")) + "\n Lieu : " + str(agenda_list[24].get("location")) + "[/color]")
    
    # Define main window's background color
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    
    # Call the main application
    ConceptruelleApp().run()
```

Comment: I don't think user-installed apps are allowed this permission, and nor do you need it. The real problem is likely something else.

Comment: It's clear that it's not my last problem with that project :D

Answer (score 1):

No ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER argument is returned because there are no such permission available for the app in that name.

The list of permissions are available in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission
and as per phonecall easiest way is you could use PLYER module.

Comment: But if I don't ask for that permission, the message pops anyway :/

Comment: Probably some part of the code is trying to access it and without seeing the code anyone might be least helpful.

Comment: I added it at the end of the main message. Sorry for not putting it the first time.

Comment: try putting Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) at the starting of the code instead of the end

Comment: My Bad its not the clearcolor... and its not the flinger i am getting a python logger in infinite loop.

Comment: A python logger in infinite loop ? I don't understand, sorry ^^

Comment: I found that Scrapy isn't working with Buildozer, I put an handmade dictionnary and commented all the scrapy stuff, the application launches on my phone.

Comment: Yeah... It was showing " [KIVY] stderr: " in a loop in logcat. It probably was one of the loggers of scrapy modules then.

Comment: And Android basic handling is much easier with plyer

Comment: Hi,
The issue was with Scrapy so I used beautifulsoup4 to get another issue with htmlparser, but found a workaround here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952484/buildozer-compiles-apk-but-it-crashes-on-android

I don't use jnius anymore and thanks to Athul Srinivas I discovered the easy way with plyer.

Today my project is like 80% done, thanks you all for your help !